# How to use browser back/forward/refresh in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I want to control my Angular 6 web application.

If user refreshes the screen, I want to give them an alert. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

if you don't want use global window inside your angular read [this blog](https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/)

Comment: it's not related to angular6 you can write this in any framework it should work. check if window objecg have onbeforeunload